# English translation of Hermias' commentary on Plato's "Phaedrus"

Tags: greek-language, plato, hermias

Does there exist an English translation of the Commentary on Plato's *Phaedrus* (*In Platonis Phaedrum Scholia*) by [Hermias of Alexandria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermias_(philosopher))?

Comment: Yes, there's one by Dirk Baltzly & Michael Share (Bloomsbury Academic, 2018).

Comment: Thank you Gareth. Looking into that now. Pricey! Hoping for one online!

Comment: That's what inter-library loan is for.

Comment: Thanks! I'll continue to try and get access via that means.

Comment: Were you looking at the hardback edition or the [paperback](https://www.bloomsbury.com/uk/hermias-on-plato-phaedrus-227a245e-9781350136489/)?

Comment: Thanks! I clicked on the link and found a reasonably priced version (£26.99). Still trying to find something online with a Greek/English translation .pdf. Sometimes I can find something on archive.org though I've come up empty looking there.